# How to keep a background image quality crisp?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I work with a survey platform and in this survey platform I am using a pre-defined template for my survey. The platform allows for CSS "modifications" and I'm trying to get the header image quality to keep from reducing. The image is uploaded as 1170*295 but needs to be displayed as 760*192.

The platform offers a simple image header uploading option but only for a certain size. My image has a lower "height" than their standard.

Things like `image-rendering: crisp-edges;` (or `-webkit-optimize-contrast`) are not doing anything. The "end text" displays in blue color (yes, I am a complete beginner and programming in any form is not part of my job).

Header image

```
div.questionnaire-header {
   background: url("/images/uploaded/ANFCZ1FSC5C2?width=760&height=192") no-repeat center left;
}
```

I hope the header image is displayed with clear, crisp text and not blurry.

Comment: Do you have to stick with the `1170x295` ratio or is there a way for you to upload a larger, higher quality image so that it doesn't need to be upscaled in code?

Answer (score 1):

Set the background-size property to 100% so our image fills the image element. Set the background-position property to 50% 50% to align the background image within the image element.

Comment: This almost solved it but it caused a new issue. The quality does indeed become higher (thanks!), but now the standard header size (which is about 200px high) is filled with the background image, showing the traces of a "double" behind the header I want. [This is what appears above and below the header](https://imgur.com/a/7NDa1Cg). Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Never mind; I solved it by simply adding some white space pixels above and below the header image. Thank you so much Priyanka for the help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is stretching to meet the size of the header. There's no real easy way to upscale an image in css and retain quality. Either change the width of the header to 760px or find an image larger than 1170 x 295

Answer (score 0):

Set the background-size property to 100% of your image to fills the image element.